# Unable to access django app on other android devices on my hotspot network

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, django, django-2.1

I created the django app and hosted the same on my laptop which was connected to my android mobile hotspot.

Then I got the IP of my machine, using ipconfig

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2d4e:f2c4:bc88:e67e%5
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.69
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
```

then I added the same to

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.43.69']
```

and ran the server using

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.43.69:8000
```

now when I am accessing the same on my laptop, I am able to access the device but when I am trying to access the same on my mobile device I am getting the same typical chrome connection error

```
The site can't be reached
192.168.43.69 took too long to respond
ERR_CONNCTION_TIMED_OUT
```

How can I resolve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to turn off windows defender for it to receive incoming traffic

[image]

One thing I still didn't get was since the request coming to my device were all internal from the device connected to my router, still why windows defender was blocking the incoming requests?

Comment: very good point

Answer (score 2):

you should run the server by using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

That way only you can access it from outside host. You still can use your host ip address to access the application.

```
ie: 192.168.43.69
```

Comment: Exactly solved my issue. I ran django app on Ubuntu desktop, and tried to consume API on Windows, but it didn't work even I enabled `ufw` for port 8000. 
After adding `0.0.0.0:8000`, it worked as expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found with the help of Himanshuman's and Yasii's answers.
I got things work for me i am mentioning below:

1. get you IP address using **ipconfig**
2. Add this IPV4 IP address to the **ALLOWED_HOSTS** list in **setting.py**
3. turn off the **firewall** on you system from settings.
4. Next step is try running the localhost using **python** **manage.py** **runserver** **0.0.0.0:8000**
5. Now go to phone and type yourIP:8000 and your project will run in your phone.

   For example 192.168.45.100:8000 will run the localhost in your phone.

This is how things worked for me. steps are in cronological order and recommended to be executed one after another